# Toyota Hard start with pop sound from the exhaust

Tags: toyota

I have Toyota corolla 2000, which is difficult to start at times and it starts normal at times.... But these days I experience pop sound when starting the engine form the exhaust..
Engine of apromx. 200k miles

Comment: Typically that represents a timing issue (either cam or spark). How many miles on the engine?

Comment: 200k. Miles on the engine

Comment: Do you have an OBD scanner? If you haven't, i recommend you get one, do an OBD scan and post any PTC codes here, provided the MIL light is on.

Comment: One thing I’d like you to try. When you go to start the car, turn the key to on. Listen for the sound of the fuel pump in the fuel tank. Let the pump run for two or three seconds. Then turn the key to the start position . Does this make a difference in start up?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a pop at start indicates excess fuel/air in the cylinder at the wrong time in the four cycle combustion process.  This could be a problem in:

- valve timing (worn chain?)
- valve sealing (burnt valve?)
- or perhaps leaky fuel injectors.

Oh, and my request for a pre-start fuel pump run is to test for leaky fuel injectors.. I'd suspect you get more "pop" at startup in that circumstance...

200,000 miles on the engine is a whole lot.  Frankly for that car, I'd suspect that is end of the engine's life expectancy. How long were you expecting this engine to last?  How noisy is it?  Any oil leaks on the ground?  (both of those indicate lots of normal use engine wear...)

Comment: How noisy is it? No noise, no oil leaks

Comment: @Gabriel One thing I’d like you to try. When you go to start the car, turn the key to on. Listen for the sound of the fuel pump in the fuel tank. Let the pump run for two or three seconds. Then turn the key to the start position . Does this make a difference in start up? – zipzit Apr 25 at 14:37

Answer (score 0):

Backfire is caused by the exhaust system containing gasoline vapor and air from cylinders that did not fire. When a cylinder fires, flame in the exhaust ignites the vapor . If severe , it can blow open a muffler/resonator. The cat converter does not have any affect when it is cold.

Comment: So, what is the The solution?